# Python 2.7 - Check if first element in two-element tuple in list of single-element tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of tuples.

The first list has tuples with two elements:

```
list_a = [('a','apple'), ('b','banana'), ('c','cherry')]
```

A second list has tuples with only one element:

```
list_b = [('d',), ('e',), ('a',)]
```

I need to remove tuples in list_a for which the first element of the tuple is included in list_b. So the goal is that list_a is rendered:

```
list_a = [('b','banana'), ('c','cherry')]
```

I've tried:

```
for la in list_a:
   if la[0] in list_b:
      list_a.remove(la)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't remove elements from a list you are looping over. Use a list comprehension instead:

```
list_a = [la for la in list_a if la[:1] not in list_b]
```

Note that we test for `la[:1]` to test with a (single element) tuple; `la[0]` is just the single character string.

If you have to do this very often, consider using a set for `list_b` instead:

```
set_b = set(list_b)
```

Lookups in a set take constant time, vs. linear time for a list membership test.

Comment: A quick explanation of [list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Comment: That's my solution. Thanks much.